# access to observer object returned by axios -vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

trying to fetch data returnd my url in axios function. but the data is not showing up.

console.log return data with this format

[image]

this is my code

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="val in values">
                        <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">{{ val.id }}</td>
                        <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">{{ val.value }}</td>
                        <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">{{ val.price }}</td>
                        <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'attribute-values',
        props: ['attributeid'],
        data() {
                return {
                    values: [],
                    value: '',
                    price: '',
                    currentId: '',
                    addValue: true,
                    key: 0,
                }
            },
    mounted(){
        this.loadValues();
    },
        methods: {
            loadValues() {
                let attributeId = this.attributeid;
                axios.post('/admin/attributes/get-values', {
                    id: attributeId
                }).then (response => {
                console.log('hello');
                    let result = response.data;
                     this.values=result;
                    console.log(this.values);
                return this.values;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

the value array is returned correctly but still cant fetch it in my table.
any idea. thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show what `values` actually looks like? The screenshot of your log output is not helpful.

Comment: i edit the post. the data is showing correctly in log.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely caused by the use of `this` within an arrow function in your response handler. Per the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods):

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback

Try changing:

```
then (response => {
```

to:

```
then (function(response) {
```

Comment: Uses `function(){}` will cause the context is not Vue component instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem therefore i will share partially my code, hopefully it will help.

```
>         <ul>
>           <li v-for="meeting in meet" :key="meeting.meeting">{{ meeting.meeting }}</li>
>         </ul>
>       </div>
> 
> 
here meetingName is from Json and this.meeting is fromfunction

>   data: () => {
>     return {
>       meet: this.meeting,
>       date: this.date,
>       meetingName: this.meeting, 


    };   
 },


  methods: {
>     async Today() {
>       await axios
>         .get("http://localhost:3001/today")
>         .then((response) => (this.meet = response.data))
>         .catch((err) => (this.meet = "No DB connection"));
>       return this.meet;
>     },
```